# Delphi - cannot build for Android

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5, firemonkey-fm3

I am unable to build applications for Android. I was able to successfully build and deploy to android devices using the Beta as well as the Trial versions of XE5. Since using XE5 professional I am unable to build for android devices. I did get the iOS os working. My SDK and NDK paths are setup correctly.

The error log is as follow:

```
[DCC Error] E2597 C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.7\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: error: cannot find -lrtlhelper
C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.7\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: error: cannot find -lcompiler_rt
c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\12.0\lib\Android\debug\SysInit.o(.ARM.exidx.text._ZN7Sysinit8__mallocEj+0x0): error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr0'
c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\12.0\lib\Android\debug\SysInit.o(.ARM.exidx.text._ZN7Sysinit10GetTlsSizeEv+0x0): error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr0'
c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\12.0\lib\Android\debug\SysInit.o(.ARM.exidx.text._ZN7Sysinit13InitThreadTLSEv+0x0): error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr0'
c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\12.0\lib\Android\debug\SysInit.o(.ARM.exidx.text._ZN7Sysinit12FinalizationEv+0x0): error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr0'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\sys/System.pas:16291: error: undefined reference to '_Unwind_Resume'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\sys/System.pas:15440: error: undefined reference to '_Unwind_Resume'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\sys/System.pas:15501: error: undefined reference to '_Unwind_Resume'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\sys/System.pas:15538: error: undefined reference to '_Unwind_Resume'
c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\12.0\lib\Android\debug\System.o(.ARM.exidx.text.__stub_in8s__ZN6System17TInterfacedObject14QueryInterfaceE5_GUIDPv+0x0): error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr1'
c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\12.0\lib\Android\debug\System.o(.ARM.exidx.text.__stub_in12v0__ZN6System16TContainedObject14QueryInterfaceE5_GUIDPv+0x0): error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr1'
c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\12.0\lib\Android\debug\System.o(.ARM.exidx.text.__stub_in16s__ZN6System17TInterfacedObject14QueryInterfaceE5_GUIDPv+0x0): error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr1'
c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\12.0\lib\Android\debug\System.o(.ARM.exidx.text._ZN6System8TMarshal17AllocStringAsAnsiEPDst+0x0): error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr1'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\sys/System.pas:6810: error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_ul2d'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\sys/System.pas:6808: error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_ul2d'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\sys/System.pas:7003: error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_ul2d'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\sys/System.pas:7001: error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_ul2d'
c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\12.0\lib\Android\debug\System.o:System:function System::_Unwind_RaiseException(_Unwind_Exception&): error: undefined reference to '_Unwind_RaiseException'
c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\12.0\lib\Android\debug\System.o:System:function System::fegetexceptflag(unsigned short*, unsigned int): error: undefined reference to 'math_fegetexceptflag'
c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\12.0\lib\Android\debug\System.o:System:function System::fesetexceptflag(unsigned short*, unsigned int): error: undefined reference to 'math_fesetexceptflag'
c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\12.0\lib\Android\debug\System.o:System:function System::fegetround(): error: undefined reference to 'math_fegetround'
c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\12.0\lib\Android\debug\System.o:System:function System::fesetround(unsigned int): error: undefined reference to 'math_fesetround'
c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\12.0\lib\Android\debug\System.o:System:function System::fegetenv(void*): error: undefined reference to 'math_fegetenv'
c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\12.0\lib\Android\debug\System.o:System:function System::fesetenv(void*): error: undefined reference to 'math_fesetenv'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\sys/System.pas:7396: error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_l2d'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\sys/System.pas:9620: error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_ldivmod'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\sys/System.pas:9621: error: undefined reference to '__moddi3'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\sys/System.pas:17091: error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_ldivmod'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\sys/System.pas:17095: error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_ldivmod'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\sys/System.pas:17119: error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_ldivmod'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\sys/System.pas:33067: error: undefined reference to '__umoddi3'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\sys/System.pas:33069: error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_uldivmod'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\sys/System.pas:33479: error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_idiv'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\sys/System.Types.pas:3352: error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_l2f'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\sys/System.Types.pas:3352: error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_l2f'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\sys/System.SysUtils.pas:29045: error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_l2f'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\sys/System.SysUtils.pas:29050: error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_l2d'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\sys/System.SysUtils.pas:29055: error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_l2d'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\sys/System.SysUtils.pas:29105: error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_ul2f'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\sys/System.SysUtils.pas:5045: error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_idiv'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\sys/System.SysUtils.pas:5046: error: undefined reference to '__modsi3'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\sys/System.SysUtils.pas:7797: error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_uldivmod'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\sys/System.SysUtils.pas:16553: error: undefined reference to '__moddi3'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\sys/System.SysUtils.pas:16655: error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_l2d'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\sys/System.SysUtils.pas:17550: error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_uldivmod'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\sys/System.SysUtils.pas:18214: error: undefined reference to '__moddi3'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\sys/System.SysUtils.pas:18334: error: undefined reference to '__moddi3'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\sys/System.VarUtils.pas:805: error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_l2f'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\sys/System.VarUtils.pas:1164: error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_ul2f'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\sys/System.Variants.pas:2438: error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_ul2f'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\common/System.Rtti.pas:2725: error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_idiv'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\common/System.Rtti.pas:2357: error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_idiv'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\common/System.Rtti.pas:3240: error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_ul2f'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\common/System.Rtti.pas:6946: error: undefined reference to 'rtti_raw_invoke'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\common/System.Rtti.pas:9229: error: undefined reference to 'rtti_raw_intercept'
c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\12.0\lib\Android\debug\System.Rtti.o:System.Rtti:function System::Rtti::AllocFirstStageIntercept(void*, void*, int): error: undefined reference to 'allocate_first_stage_intercept'
c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\12.0\lib\Android\debug\System.Rtti.o:System.Rtti:function System::Rtti::FreeIntercept(System::Rtti::TMethodImplementation::TFirstStageIntercept*): error: undefined reference to 'free_first_stage_intercept'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\common/System.Classes.pas:14741: error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_uldivmod'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\fmx/FMX.Effects.pas:863: error: undefined reference to '__modsi3'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\fmx/FMX.Effects.pas:890: error: undefined reference to '__modsi3'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\fmx/FMX.Effects.pas:891: error: undefined reference to '__modsi3'
C:\Builds\TP\runtime\rtl\android/Androidapi.JNIBridge.pas:365: error: undefined reference to 'DispatchToImport'
```

Comment: You did a complete uninstall before installing? I was bitten by the need to have about 60GB free space on the disk before installation.

Comment: This is an installation related issue. Embarcadero support would be the proper place to ask this question, as they have specifics about how to deal with installation problems. You can open a free support case for installation related issues at http://support.embarcadero.com

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and following the steps in this Embarcadero forum fixed my issue:
https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=676070

> Ensure that $(BDSLIB)\$(PLATFORM)\Release appears in the library path
>   for Android apps (Tools-Options->Delphi->Library paths and selected
>   platform=Android).